# Customizing Ribbon in Lead entity dynamic CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In lead form ribbon, I added two buttons with the help of VisualRibbonEditor. After that I deleted with the help of VisualRibbonEditor. But when I see RibbonDiffXML, still both buttons exists even though they are not visbile in Ribbon.

Here are my questions

1. How can I remove those two button entries? Do I have to create a new solution?
2. I want to add a new button and customise ConvertLead functionality. Without VisualRibbonEditor how can I achieve this manually i.e., with the help of solution file.

Comment: Since point 1 is answered, if you can't figure out the answer to point 2, it'd probably make more sense to break it up into another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml is just that, xml.  So if you have an element in it you no longer want, edit the xml by following these steps.

1. Create a new solution with just the lead entity in it (or if the ribbon editor created one, you can reuse that one, it's just easier to work with less xml rather than more).
2. Open the solution zip, find the lead entity xml file, and edit it with you're favorite xml editor, deleting the elements you no longer want/need.
3. Save your changes back to the zip file, then import the solution.

As far as editing the ribbon, [here](http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/10/understanding-crm-ribbon-xml-part-1.html) is a great site to get you started: